# Is it ok to use both MATCH AGAINST and LIKE in one MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, search-engine, sql-like, match-against

I noticed that `MATCH AGAINST` cannot search words that have 3 characters or less. So I added `LIKE` along with `MATCH AGAINST` in **one** query.

**Search query:** css and javascript tip

**Database entries:**

```
id | subject
------------------------------------
1  | ten useful css tricks
------------------------------------
2  | performance tip for javascript
```

**MySQL query:**

3-character words: css, tip

```
SELECT id, MATCH (subject) AGAINST ('css and javascript tip' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
FROM articles WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST ('css and javascript tip')
OR subject LIKE '%css%' OR subject LIKE '%tip%'
```

This query works fine on my application (with a small database). I'm not sure if it's gonna cause any problems as the database grows.

Is this the correct way to search 3-character words while using MATCH AGAINST? If not, as for the example I provided, how should I seach for **css** and **javascript** at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I do it with ~100K of rows and it isn't slow.
I think there are alternatives, but for me this is still enough:)

Here's an example:

```
//...
$tokens = explode(' ',$s));
$squery = '';
array_map('trim', $tokens);

foreach($tokens as $token){
    if(strlen($token)>3)
        $squery .= "+$token* ";
    else
        $where .= " AND title LIKE '%$token%'";
if(!empty($squery))
    $select .= " , MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$squery' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score "
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, You can change the minimum words in the system variables of Mysql. Edit the my.ini file located usually in the programdata/mysql/mysql server 5.x directory. Sometimes you have to copy the my.ini file inside the program files/mysql/mysql server ver 5.x for it to work. As i have experienced for windows server 2003 and 2008 while the first one works in Windows 7.

insert the following below [mysqld]:

```
ft_min_word_len = 2  
ft_stopword_file = ""
```

Restart Mysql, you can do this in the services, stop and play or which ever you know.

Then re-index your table, make sure the engine is MYISAM. Although lately InnoDB works too.

The ft_stop_word_file is the one that causes some of the words to be excluded from matching. You can either equal it to "" or point to a plain text file where you want if you have a stopword file. You can create your own stopword file example mystopword.txt, inside will be words separated with space which you do not want to include in matching.